# How can I predict single sample of data using min max scaler when I am training the model with min max scaled data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, normalization, scaling, test-data

As explained in [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54920707/how-can-i-fit-the-test-data-using-min-max-scaler-when-i-am-loading-the-model#new-answer), one can easily test the data when you have a set of samples.
If the user has to predict the target of a single sample, then how to proceed. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: There should be no difference: `scaled_sample = scaler.transform(sample)`

Comment: scaler=MinMaxScaler()
x_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)


a=scaler.transform(x_test.iloc[0,:])              When I do scaling for a single sample I am facing following error                                                                                                                                                            Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: @Dan Thanks! Can you please above case which I tried. My requirement is to test each sample after training the model. Can you please help me in this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the same `MinMaxScaler()` object you've used while training to transform your single instance. Here's an example.

```
# training data
X_train = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
y_train = np.array([1, 0])

# scaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler().fit(X_train)
```

Scaling `X_train`:

```
X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
```

Train the model using X_train_scaled and y_train ...

---

Predicting on the new sample `np.array([7, 8])`:

```
new_sample = np.array([7, 8]).reshape(1, -1)  # because the scaler expects a 2D array
scaler.transform(new_sample)  # pass this to model.predict()
```

---

**Edit:**

How Min-Max Normalization works:

The following transformation is applied to each feature [(Wikipedia Link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling#Rescaling_(min-max_normalization)):

[image]

We will apply that to `X_train`

```
X_train = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])

array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])

# min, max of each feature
mn = np.min(X_train, axis=0)  # array([1, 2])
mx = np.max(X_train, axis=0)  # array([5, 6])
```

Calculating the scaled version:

```
(X_train - mn) / (mx - mn)

array([[0. , 0. ],
   [0.5, 0.5],
   [1. , 1. ]])
```

The above matches with the result of:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)

array([[0. , 0. ],
       [0.5, 0.5],
       [1. , 1. ]])
```

When you supply a new input vector, the same transformation should apply using the above `mn` and `mx` values

```
new_smaple = np.array([7, 8]).reshape(1, -1)
(new_sample - mn) / (mx - mn)

array([[1.5, 1.5]])
```

This matches the output of `scaler.transform(new_sample)`

Also, you can extract min, max from a fitted MinMaxScaler object using `scaler.data_min_` and `scaler.data_max_` which will match the above `mn` and `mx`.

Comment: As per my knowledge : In the case of reshaping np.array(-1,1) , we are transforming the single sample from row form to column. Then scaler will rescale the sample based on the information present in column form . Doesnt we loosing any information. Can you please help in understanding how the rescaling will work from the scaler features of x_train.